# Very very slow Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to automate  process that I have to do every day at work by dumping a pool of data and reformatting it. I have been working on this for quite a while and the last place I thought I'd be would was on a forum asking for help. I've done some research and have included as many of the recommendations that i could find in my macro. When I 1st created the macro I had all of the "Select"ing in there and it was running fast. As i kept running it for trial purposes it got slower and slower. Now it takes 2 minutes or more to complete and within the 1st 5 seconds it stops responding and then 2-3 minutes later it is done.

The purpose of this is to reformat information for a sheet that is look at and to create a sheets based on the date to prioritize the information. All of the date is linked to a sheet call "Hot Sheet" but I create a new sheet and then switch over the formula references so Excel doesn't over work itself. I am a novice and self taught so please go easy on me.

PS: As I am saving the file it now prompts me saying: "Privacy Warning: This document contains macros, ActiveX Controls, XML expansions pack information, or Web components. These may include personal information that cannot be removed by the Document Inspector."

Code:

```
ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1"
Columns("A:A").Select
Range("A4").Activate
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:= _
    True

Rows("1:3").Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range("A1:T1").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Range("A1:T1").Merge
Range("A1:T1").FormulaR1C1 = "ASCP Planner Overview Report"
Range("A4").FormulaR1C1 = "Input Perameters"
Rows("5:37").ClearContents
Range("B4").ClearContents
Range("B5").FormulaR1C1 = "Instance Name"
Range("B6").FormulaR1C1 = "MRP Plan Name"
Range("B7").FormulaR1C1 = "Organization Code"
Range("B8").FormulaR1C1 = "Bucket Type"
Range("B9").FormulaR1C1 = "Report Type"
Range("B10").FormulaR1C1 = "Planner"
Range("B11").FormulaR1C1 = "Planner user name"
Range("B12").FormulaR1C1 = "Planner Lookup"
Range("B13").FormulaR1C1 = "Supplier"
Range("B14").FormulaR1C1 = "SC Total"
Range("B15").FormulaR1C1 = "Make / Buy"
Range("B16").FormulaR1C1 = "Net Shortage Only"
Range("B17").FormulaR1C1 = "Shortage Cutoff Date"
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range("A40:F40").Cut Destination:=Range("E13:J13")
Rows("43:61").Delete Shift:=xlUp

On Error Resume Next
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
PrevCalc = .Calculation
.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With
Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 11
Range("T41").FormulaR1C1 = "Page 1"
 Range("E50").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-5]C[-2]"
Range("E50").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E50:T50"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("B43").CutCopyMode = False
Range("F49").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-6]C[-2]&R[-6]C[-1]&R[-6]C&R[-6]C[1]"
Range("F49").Copy
Range("F49").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("E50:T50").Copy
Range("E50:T50").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Rows("43:48").ClearContents
Range("A43").FormulaR1C1 = "ORG"
Range("A44").FormulaR1C1 = "Planner"
Range("A45").FormulaR1C1 = "Sourcing Rule"
Range("A46").FormulaR1C1 = "OH Qty-Insp"
Range("A47").FormulaR1C1 = "Negative"
Range("A48").FormulaR1C1 = "OH-Consign"
Range("B43").FormulaR1C1 = "Item Number"
Range("B44").FormulaR1C1 = "Make/Buy"
Range("B46").FormulaR1C1 = "OH Qty-Total"
Range("B47").FormulaR1C1 = "In trans Qty"
Range("B48").FormulaR1C1 = "LT (Post P)"

        Range("93:93,95:112,155:155,157:174,217:217,219:236,279:279,281:298,341:341,343:360,403:403    ,405:422").Delete Shift:=xlUp
Rows("351:351").Delete Shift:=xlUp
Rows("352:369").Delete Shift:=xlUp
Rows("394:394").Delete Shift:=xlUp
Rows("395:412").Delete Shift:=xlUp
Rows("437:437").Delete Shift:=xlUp
Rows("440:455").Delete Shift:=xlUp
Rows("439:439").Delete Shift:=xlUp
Rows("481:481").Delete Shift:=xlUp

Range("57:57,63:63,69:69,75:75,81:81,87:87").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Rows("99:101").Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range("F101").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-52]C"
Range("E102:T102").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-52]C"
Range("E102:T102").Select
Range("109:109,115:115,121:121,127:127,133:133,139:139").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Rows("151:153").Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range("F153").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-52]C"
Range("E154:T154").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-52]C"
Range("E154:T154").Select
Range("161:161,167:167,173:173,179:179,185:185,191:191").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Rows("203:205").Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range("F205").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-52]C"
Range("E206:T206").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-52]C"
Range("E206:T206").Select
Range("213:213,219:219,225:225,231:231,237:237,243:243").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Rows("255:257").Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range("F257").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-52]C"
Range("E258:T258").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-52]C"
Range("E258:T258").Select
Range("265:265,271:271,277:277,283:283,289:289,295:295").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Rows("307:309").Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range("F309").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-52]C"
Range("E310:T310").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-52]C"
Range("E310:T310").Select
Range("317:317,323:323,329:329,335:335,341:341,347:347").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Rows("359:361").Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range("F361").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-52]C"
Range("E362:T362").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-52]C"
Range("E362:T362").Select
Range("369:369,375:375,381:381,387:387,393:393,399:399").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Rows("411:413").Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range("F413").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-52]C"
Range("E414:T414").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-52]C"
Range("421:421,427:427,433:433,439:439,445:445,451:451").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Rows("463:465").Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range("F465").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-52]C"
Range("E466:T466").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-52]C"
Range("473:473,479:479,485:485,491:491,497:497,503:503").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Rows("515:517").Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range("F517").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-52]C"
Range("E518:T518").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-52]C"
Rows("519:519").Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("525:525,531:531,537:537,543:543,549:549,555:555").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
.Calculation = PrevCalc
End With

On Error Resume Next

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
Cells.Select
Range("C562").Activate
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
    Formula1:="=0"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16383844
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13551615
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Range("A50").Select
    Union(Range( _
    "B291,B298,B305,B315,B322,B329,B336,B343,B350,B357,B367,B374,B381,B388,B395,B402,B409,B419,B426,B55,B62,B69,B76,B83,B90,B97,B107,B114,B121,B128,B135,B142" _
    ), Range( _
    "B149,B159,B166,B173,B180,B187,B194,B201,B211,B218,B225,B232,B239,B246,B253,B263,B270,B277,B284" _
    )).Select
Range("B426").Activate
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
    Formula1:="=0"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16752384
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13561798
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Range("A401").Select
Range("A51").Select

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
ActiveSheet.Select
Sheets("View1").Delete
ActiveSheet.Name = "View1"
Sheets("Hot Sheet").Select
Cells.Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$524").AutoFilter Field:=4
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$524").AutoFilter Field:=1
Selection.Replace What:="View2", Replacement:="View1", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Sheets("View1").Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
Sheets("View1 (2)").Select
Sheets("View2").Delete
Sheets("View1 (2)").Name = "View2"
Sheets("Hot Sheet").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Replace What:="View1", Replacement:="View2", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$524").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
"NA:ASH", "NA:DLM", "NA:FOR", "NA:FRK", "NA:LRS", "NA:MON", "NA:NWK", "NA:YRB", _
"NA:YRK"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
Range("A1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hint, don't use copy and paste, but assign values in array ranges with `Sheets("View2").Range("A1:D500").Value = Sheets("View1").Range("A1:D500").Value` for example.

Comment: And do not use `Insert()` to move cells, just place the cells in the correct row to begin with.

Comment: It's .Range2 not Range if you want to optimise passing in an array

Comment: Where is this data coming from? A database? I suggest you write an efficient query to get the data from the database in the format you want. It's difficult to tell what you're doing from that enormous piece of code. If you have a performance issue you need to monitor your code and try and analyse where the issue is and focus on that. The fact is Excel has scalability limits and basing your business processes on Excel macros is a liability

Comment: I'm sorry that why i wrote so much to begin with to answer the questions. It is a data dump from a text file. So. Ja72 i will try the array, but i insert to help format. I am converting a PDF file to a text file then trying to duplicate the format of the PDF file in Excel for analytically purposes. so EletricLlama there is no query. There is just jumbled crap I am trying to sort through.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off screen updating to free up system resources. You might have other issues with your macro, but you should notice a marked improvement in performance.

at the beginning of your macro add:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

At the end (right before 'End Sub") add:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I have tried this one. I didn't really notice a improvement. I was just disappointing because the more tips is was following to make this things go faster the slower it seemed to become. I thought maybe it was the fact that it was a company computer. But as i said in the original post. When it was selecting the sells, you did have to watch it jump around but it didnt freeze and it went strait through faster.

Answer (score 1):

Where to start? btw don't take it the wrong way, its clear you already know how to get Excel to do what you want with VBA these tips are more about addressing your question in terms of performance.

1. Application.ScreenUpdating = False (at start) turn back on at end.
2. you seem to have a preference for using R1C1 notation with formulas, replace that with a pattern that gets all input data from each of your cell blocks into a 2 dimensional array, via .Range2 property.
3. do all transformations of data using loops to update values in the array as necessary.
4. write the array back to a cell range of the exact same size passing in the array to the .Range2 property.
5. The With blocks look pretty harmless you can leave them.
6. Move the formatting conditions right to the end unless you need it earlier (you shouldn't).
7. add a table (listobject) and convert your range to that. then use the data block to reference the data you'll be modifying in tip (2.) above.
8. use the table to insert rows if you have to. however you'd be better off, working with the data in an array, adding rows (elements) as necessary within the array, then calculating the new array size and writing that back as per tips (2. through 4.).

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps give you a little more information but i added something in that creates a new workbook and recreates everything in the new workbook. and it does it all in about 5 seconds. does this mean once i save the workbook it just gets a lot slower?